# Is there any way to edit all classes in a folder to inherit from certain base class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have 60 or so classes in a folder and I created a base class for those classes to inherit from.

Is there any automatic way to do this other than copy&paste method in Visual Studio?

I hoped resharper has some functionality for that but can't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate the cut/paste process by using the search and replace feature of Visual Studio to find all declarations, and replace them with declarations that inherit from your base class.

- Press [Ctrl+H] to open Quick Replace
- Enter `public class {:i}` in the "Find what" box
- Enter `public class \1 : MyBaseClass` in the "Replace with:" box
- Choose "Current Project" in the "Look in:" box
- Check the "Use:" checkbox, and pick "Regular expressions" in the dropdown

Keep clicking `[Find Next]` to find the next occurrence of a class declaration. If the search highlights one of the sixty declarations that you want to modify, click `[Replace]`, otherwise keep clicking `[Find Next]`.

Comment: Some of the classes implement interfaces so I had to adjust the search string but it's working well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's quick and dirty, but yeah it works. You'll still have to do it manually every time you add a class in there.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin, if you have that adjusted search string 9 years after, would be great if you could add it here :)

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should do the trick:

```
(.*)?(class .*)?(.*)?{
```

it match any number of characters, followed by the word 'class', followed by any number of characters, followed by a curly bracket.

Perform a replace inside all your code files, using this as replacement text:

```
$1 : yourBaseClassName {
```

This has been tested with [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) online regexp validator, which handles js regexps, and assumes your files **do not** already implement subclasses / interfaces. Raw, but can be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a tool and use it as [pre build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx).

That tool could be a simple silent command line executable, that writes `: MyBaseClass` to the right of anything that looks like: `class MyClassName`.
And it would take a path as argument and do it for every *.cs file it finds in there.

This is, as far as I know, the closest to what you want to achieve.

You could also try to leverage AOP (attribute oriented programming), with a tool like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (not free), but then you have to tag every class with an attribute, which defeats your purpose.